# Variable indefinida al igualarse dentro de una promesa en VUE

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Holaaa, estoy tratando de asignar a una variable el valor que me retorna una api que consumo desde axios en vue, el caso es que al momento de igualar la variable,con el valor del response, quiero imprimir el valor de esa variable fuera de la promesa, pero me dice que es undefined, aquí el código

```
get_balance () {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
      var val = 0
      axios.get('api/service?param=' + this.token)
        .then(function (response) {
          val = response.data.resultado
        })
      console.log('El balance es ' + val)
    }
```

Si imprimo el valor de response.data.resultado el lo muestra bien, pero al quereserlo igualar a la variable var, y luego imprimir esa variable me dice que

```
'El balance es  undefined'
```

Si me pueden ayudar, se los agradecería bastante

Comment: No da , me aparece que no se puede declarar a un valor indefinido, Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'val' of undefined
    at eval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso es porque estas queriendo asignar un valor a `val` que todavia no existe, recordar que al hacer `axios.get` estas haciendo una petición asíncrona que la respuesta no es instantánea, la respuesta de la petición viene en la función `.then`, eso significa que el código haría algo como esto

1. declarar variable `val = 0`
2. enviar petición GET
3. imprimir `console.log`
4. respuesta de la petición

para poder ver el valor que viene de la petición deberías ejecutar tu `console.log` dentro de la función `.then` ya que el valor de la respuesta solo se esta disponible dentro de la misma función `.then`

```
get_balance () {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
      var val = 0
      axios.get('api/service?param=' + this.token)
        .then(function (response) {
          val = response.data.resultado
          console.log('El balance es ' + val)
        })
    }
```

para manipular el valor y reflejarlo en el DOM directamente podrías ejecutar lo que necesitas en la respuesta

```
.then(function (response) {
  val = response.data.resultado
  console.log('El balance es ' + val)
  document.querySelector('#balance').innerHTML = val
})
```

guardarla en una variable global también es posible

```
.then(function (response) {
  window.balance = response.data.resultado
  console.log('El balance es ' + window.balance)
})
```

Comment: Entonces como haría para manipular ese valor de la respuesta, es decir, tomar lo que retorna axios y declararla a una variable global que luego pueda manipular en el DOM

Comment: te dejo un ejemplo en la respuesta

Comment: Pero fuero de la promesa, cómo lo haría?

Comment: al meterla en el window.balance ya la puedes acceder desde fuera de la promesa, siempre y cuando sea fuera de la función `get_balance`, accedes al valor de la respuesta con la variable `window.balance`

Comment: Si te resolvió marcar la respuesta como aceptada , gracias

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, la verdad solucionaste mi problema, estoy muy agradecido